# Network Traffic

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, qemu

I am very much new to networking.I have one basic question.

I am writing some experimental code,where in guest vm has to receive and transfer the data rate limit fashion.To do this, the packets I get from host to vm will be chopped down and will send it as a N distinct data bytes.But in guest os I see some bytes are missing.

The question here is when I send packet data slowly, why guest not waiting for the other half,before declaring it missed some packets.

main question is how the networking works when the bandwidth is limited.Please explain.

Thanks in advance
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which OS you are using and how are you limiting the bandwidth. What protocol you are using. If it is TCP then it will report the missing packet and there will be retransmissions of missing packet.

To answer the generic question of how networking works with limited bandwidth, there is no difference, except that some latency sensitive or bandwidth hungry applications may fail/stop working. But nothing happens to packet as such. For example,

```
   1. when I download using 256Kbps limit, it take long time to download a 100MB file,
      but it will be downloaded safely without any issue.
   2. Gmail doesn't load all the features and doesn't show the rich look in 256Kbps line.
```